# Посчитать количество различных чисел в упорядоченной последовательности

Tags: c++

Дан список, упорядоченный по неубыванию элементов в нем. Определите, сколько в нем различных элементов.

```
    #include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;
int main() {
    int n, i, z;
    cin >> n;
    z = 0;
    vector <int> a(n);
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        cin >> a[i];
        if (a[i + 1] != a[i])
        {
            z++;
        }
    }
    cout << z;
    return 0;
}
```

Что-то не работает. В чём проблема?

Comment: Пара намеков. Вам совсем не нужно хранить все элементы, надо только последний введенный - и сравнивать с вновь вводимым. Можно и так, как у вас... только смотрите - вы вводите i-й элемент и сравниваете его с *еще не введенным* i+1-м...

Comment: Да, невнимательность всё) А насчет "не нужно хранить все элементы" - то есть cin сунуть в цикл предлагаете?

Comment: Конечно. Ввели первый, запомнили. Далее в цикла - читаем следующий, сравниваем, делаем выводы :), сохраняем последний считанный в той переменной, где был первый...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В if попробуйте написать -, должно всё получиться

Comment: Действительно, от усталости невнимательность, видимо) Спасибо!